# Not getting UI display with Skia library tests on ubuntu

Tags: skia

I followed the steps from [skia site](https://sites.google.com/site/skiadocs/user-documentation/quick-start-guides/linux) for compiling skia r1236 on my Ubuntu 12.04 64 bit machine.
When i run the tests ,  no window comes up to show the graphical result.The output on console is :

*[1/33] PDFPrimitives...
...................
[33/33] BitmapCopy...
Finished 33 tests, 0 failures.*

If i put a Bitmap to a file using SkImageEncoder::EncodeFile  , i do get graphical output on the file. This confirms that the library is working fine but is not able to invoke linux window system.

Another problem is that while running text , i get following error

*SkFontHost::OpenStream failed opening 1
--- no context for glyph 0*

I have installed all freetype libraries as described by the [Skia website](https://sites.google.com/site/skiadocs/user-documentation/quick-start-guides/linux) , but still have error whichever path i use in SK_FONT_FILE_PREFIX.

My "/usr/share/fonts/" folder have

- cmap
- truetype
- type1
- X11

I noticed there is a file SkOSWIndow_Unix.cpp but nobody seems to be calling it from the test code.So my question is

1) How do we get the output to be shown on a window?

2) WHat should be the value of SK_FONT_FILE_PREFIX?

PS : The Windows port worked fine

Answer (score 0):

Skia r1236 is at least two years old; you should be using something newer. The directions on the website are less than a year old.

The Linux tests and the Windows tests produce the same thing. You should see the same result from Linux as you did from Windows.

Part of the question is *which* particular tests you are running. From your description of the Linux shell output, these were the "gm" tests, which do not display windows. They draw pictures onto off-screen canvases.

With the "-w " option, gm will write the images as pngs into a directory.
With the "-r " option, gm will read images from a directory and compare them to the images it generates.

The SampleApp application in Skia does use the Linux window system. However, we do not support the "views" library that was used to create it. Skia is a platform-independent rendering engine; you'll need to provide your own windows management.

- Note that gm functions a bit differently since somtime in the 6000s or 7000s; a default checkout will no longer contain the reference images for all GMs on all platforms.